# Why querying the DNS of test.com always return something?

Tags: dns

While playing with the DNS of test.com, I discovered that if I query anything, I get a valid response.

For example:

```
dig superuser-is-awesome.test.com -t TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.10.5-P2-RedHat-9.10.5-2.P2.fc25 <<>> superuser-is-awesome.test.com -t TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52365
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;superuser-is-awesome.test.com. IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
superuser-is-awesome.test.com. 7200 IN TXT  "v=spf1 ~all"

;; Query time: 133 msec
;; SERVER: 89.2.0.1#53(89.2.0.1)
;; WHEN: ven. sept. 01 14:28:12 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 86
```

It works the same with type `A` or even no type at all:

```
dig superuser-is-awesome.test.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.5-P2-RedHat-9.10.5-2.P2.fc25 <<>> superuser-is-awesome.test.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9026
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;superuser-is-awesome.test.com. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
superuser-is-awesome.test.com. 3600 IN  A   69.172.200.109

;; Query time: 130 msec
;; SERVER: 89.2.0.1#53(89.2.0.1)
;; WHEN: ven. sept. 01 14:29:20 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 74
```

How is that possible? Is there a way to get the real value (should be nothing, except if truly exists)?

Comment: Your url redirects to test.com. Try with `curl -I`, you can see the redirected url.

Comment: I'm using dig, not curl.

Comment: I was thinking this is something to do with a wildcard DNS entry, but they don't seem to have one.

Comment: I was not aware that something like this was possible on DNS.

Comment: But yes, it appears to be a wildcard, if you query `dig *.test.com`, you'll get the same results!

Comment: @Darren I'll let you post an answer and I'll accept it (if you want).

Comment: @CyrilN. I will post an answer as I’ve already written it and it might be of interest. Don’t accept it just yet though as I’m not convinced it’s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DISCLAIMER***: I'm not convinced this is a correct answer, but I am posting it anyway at the request of the OP.

---

`test.com` is a real domain, [registered by a company](https://who.is/whois/test.com) called "Perfect Privacy, LLC" in Florida.

A domain can have a [wildcard DNS entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) created for it.

> This wildcard DNS record will cause DNS lookups on domain names ending
>   in example.com that do not exist to have MX records synthesized for
>   them. So, a lookup for the MX record for somerandomname.example.com
>   would return an MX record pointing to host1.example.com.

However, [the DNS records](http://www.viewdns.info/dnsrecord/?domain=test.com) for test.com do not indicate they have a wildcard entry that I can see:

```
DNS Records for test.com
==============

Name        TTL     Class  Type     Priority    Data
test.com.   7200    IN     SOA                  NS65.WORLDNIC.com. namehost.WORLDNIC.com. 117070512 10800 3600 604800 3600
test.com.   7200    IN     NS                   ns65.worldnic.com.
test.com.   7200    IN     NS                   ns66.worldnic.com.
test.com.   3600    IN     A                    69.172.200.235
test.com.   7200    IN     TXT                  "google-site-verification=kW9t2V_S7WjOX57zq0tP8Ae_WJhRwUcZoqpdEkvuXJk"
test.com.   7200    IN     MX       30          lastmx.spamexperts.net.
test.com.   7200    IN     MX       20          fallbackmx.spamexperts.eu.
test.com.   7200    IN     MX       10          mx.spamexperts.com.
```

Comment: There is a wildcard record in the zone, you have to query specifically for it: `dig \*.test.com A` does indeed return `*.test.com.  1h IN A 69.172.200.109`. The wildcard record is a valid record in the DNS by itself like any other records, its presence just triggers additionnal processing in authoritative nameservers... Same for `dig \*.test.com TXT`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek. Interesting. Would you like to update my answer accordingly? I wouldn't be offended.

Comment: if you want, just add the dig command and output. You can remove your disclaimer, your answer is correct. As for ViewDNS they show the records on `test.com` and hence can not show the wildcard (and do not accept * as a valid character in their form anyway). Note that (since I see it in another comment), `dig \*.test.com` and `dig *.test.com` are two different things since `*` is also a shell metacharacter, so it is often better to protect it (to be sure it is not replaced by something else before being used), even if the final DNS packet will indeed be for `*.test.com`.

Answer (score 2):

These are wildcard DNS entries. Tested it on my own DNS Server, this it how it looks:

[image]

```
dig hans.xxx.xxx.net TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.15-Ubuntu <<>> hans.xxx.xxx.net TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64899
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hans.xxx.xxx.net.           IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hans.xxx.xxx.net.    3600    IN      TXT     "Test"

;; Query time: 22 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.2.166#53(10.0.2.166)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 01 15:13:36 DST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65

dig hans.xxx.xxx.net

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.15-Ubuntu <<>> hans.xxx.xxx.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42482
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hans.xxx.xxx.net.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hans.xxx.xxx.net.    3600    IN      A       10.0.2.81

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.2.166#53(10.0.2.166)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 01 15:19:46 DST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```